# Office 365 Installation TPM malfunctioned

Tags: office365, tpm

Troubleshooting a WIN10 office 365 installation - it works fine BUT I cannot verify the office 365 license (we use intermedia office365 ) - I get a TPM error 80090034 - any ideas?

Getting Office 365 working on our systems has been a problem, it should not take 4 or 5 hours to install and troubleshoot.

Or could I just buy office 365 with a license serial number?

thanks for the time in advance.

Comment: What exactly is "intermedia office365"?  You should [edit] your question to clarify it.  Can you provide a screenshot of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb`?  In my research his is a GPO policy, you are likely going to have to escalate it to your IT Administrator, so they can resolve the group policy conflict.  If you are using a VPN that is likely the cause.

Comment: Here is a similar thread, you can have a look, '[TPM error 80090034](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/tpm-error-80090034/eae555de-16ee-4f0d-ac3a-3a56cf38b30f)'.

Comment: found a fix - on youtube - never find a registry hack on youtube :(

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZPhnV3isEA

intermedia office 365 is a bit of a 1/2 whatever of office365 - we need to get off of it.